# How smart is the compiler at optimizing string concatenation.

Tags: c#, .net, clr, compiler-optimization, string-concatenation

I'm curious about how the C# compiler would treat the two statements below:

```
String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
text = text.Substring( 0, 15 );
text = text + "...";
```

vs.

```
String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
text = text.Substring( 0, 15 ) + "...";
```

The result is the same of course, but does the concatenation operator optimize the code better in the second setup?

Do you end up with 4 allocations for the strings on the stack in both cases or does the second case only allocate 3?

Just a random question I had while reading some code.

Comment: No; they are completely identical.

Comment: If you want more information about String concatenation, Eric Lippert have just started a new series on his blog [String concatenation behind the scenes, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/) and [two](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/24/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-two/)

Comment: As far I know,string concatenation with `+` operator are converted to `string.Concat()` call. If you have a lot of them, just use `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and compiled it in a simple Console application.  Then, I examined the IL (using ILSpy).  No optimizations were made in either Debug or Release mode.

In this case, the code is probably simple enough that the compiler didn't make any optimizations.  However, more complicated versions might yield different results.

Also, note that there are very few differences between the two examples.  In both cases, the runtime will end up making four different string objects.  In the first example, assignment to a variable is only done twice, whereas in the second example assignment is done three times.  However, the four strings are created, regardless.  They are as follows:

- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
- "abcdefghijklmno" (from Substring)
- "..."
- "abcdefghijklmno..." (from concatenation)

The first three strings will be almost immediately eligible for garbage collection in both cases.  I'm guessing the compiler didn't see any significant ways to improve what you have.

Comment: Literal strings are interned by default so they might not be as swiftly collected. I don't know one way or the other if the GC is less aggressive on interned strings but it seems plausible.

Comment: Fair.  It's probably more accurate to say that the objects created for those strings are eligible for garbage collection.  The first and third strings will be maintained in the string intern pool, although, they'll only be valuable if we use the exact literal string again.  Good catch!

Answer (score 10):

First off, strings are not allocated on the stack in the first place. Strings are on the heap.

Second, there are four allocations in both cases. I am curious as to which one you thought might disappear.

Coincidentally this is the subject of my blog this week. See [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/) for more than you ever wanted to know on this subject.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was smart enough to concat the literal with the substring as one action without allocating the substring separately. It seemed far fetched, but I was curious.

Comment: @HunterLewis `Substring` is a method that returns a `string`. The only way I can see that would avoid allocating that `string` is if the C# compiler somehow inlined the `Substring()` method. Is that what you expected?

Comment: That's close enough to what I was pondering. The more I think about it the less sense it makes. :)